# Java Programming Error: Actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, switch-statement

All I am trying to do here is have the user inputted integer from the "displayMenu" method control the switch statement above in the main method. But I get the following error in this picture when I compile:

[This is the error message I get when I compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yQZx.jpg)

The error basically states that my actual and informal arguments differ in length.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int userChoice = displayMenu();

    switch(userChoice) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
    }
}

public static int displayMenu(int userSelection) {  
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    userSelection = keyboard.nextInt();
    return userSelection;
}
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, it will highlight such mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the parameter from the displayMenu method.

Use

```
public static int displayMenu()
```

instead of

```
public static int displayMenu(int userSelection)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong: you're calling displayMenu without a parameter, and it requires one, an int to be precise.